# Installed 14.04 LTS... Wifi works for a while, then disconnects... requires reboot

Tags: 14.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm having an issue with my laptop using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS, and i'm not very savvy at linux at all, is when i'm using the wifi, it'll disconnect from the internet after a while... and then i'll need to reboot the machine to get it working until it disconnects again...

Here's my laptop...

HP Stream 13-c010nr 13.3″ Notebook - Celeron N2840 2.16 GHz - 2 GB RAM - 32 GB SSD

Any advice would be most appreciated... Thanks...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score -1):

Download and install this Wifi Driver.. This original driver is very unstable on the hp stream when using Ubuntu.

[Click Here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)

Extract and make install then reboot your Hp Stream. You will not have any more Wifi dropping problems anymore.